# "Physical" part of safety measures

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I want to know what the "physical" counterpart to safety measures is called. An example: we take safety measures, such as securing our home from illegal entrance. This may take form of installing locks and alarms, but how would you refer to the physical implementations of these safety measures?

I understand safety measures as something abstract, referring to the idea of securing my home with a lock or an alarm. But if I'm about to talk, generally, of these installations taken as safety measures, what do I call them? Especially if the kind of safety measures taken is not fully known to me. I don't think "installing safety measures" or "disabling safety measures" are the proper way to describe the activity of installing alarms and locks, or disabling them.

EDIT: My example may have been a poor one, as it has been suggested that security measures is a better way of describing it that safety measures. I want to emphasize however that I am also interested in the physical counterpart to safety measures, as well as security measures (not restricted to alarms and locks, or even home security), if there is a difference. I suspect that security measures may be only one kind of safety measure, and that there may be other types of measures which may be characterized under the umbrella term of safety measures.

Comment: **Practical** aspects of security and safety measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it looks as though you're talking about "security measures" rather than "safety measures". It may seem like a niggle, but the two are not the same .  At any rate, you might refer to the *stuff* as "security equipment" or "security devices".  If referring to a set of interconnected equipment, you might call it a "security system".

Comment: Perhaps that is a better description of my example, but in that case the fault lies with the example. My intention is to understand the physical part of safety measures in particular. Could you extend this answer to cover "safety measures" as well?

Comment: @Bubbles: equipment, devices and system will also pair with safety in the same fashion as they do with security.

Answer (score 0):

> You install **"home security devices"** which may include installing: motion sensor lights, surveillance cameras, several kinds of alarm, burglar-bars for windows, etc. 
>   There are several firms that offer a complete **"home security system".**

Also you can  take some security measures like having a loud (not necessarily strong) dog, closed doors and windows when away from home, additional locks, etc.

To answer your question, a surveillance camera is considered "**home security equipment**" or "**a home security device.**

Answer (score 0):

[**Physical security**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_security)

> Physical security describes security measures that are designed to deny unauthorized access to facilities, equipment and resources, and to protect personnel and property from damage or harm (such as espionage, theft, or terrorist attacks). Physical security involves the use of multiple layers of interdependent systems which include CCTV surveillance, security guards, protective barriers, locks, access control protocols, and many other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the verb "safeguarding" to refer to the action of installing safety and security devices and equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "precautions" goes a bit better with "safety," and if so, maybe **taking/practicing/observing/installing//ignoring [good] safety precautions** would work better than "measures."